# Mutiple buttons on different views with same functionality

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am new in developing IOS apps. I have made 3 custom buttons on a view. and on 3 other views i want to add those buttons at the bottom of the application with same functionality as on the main view. all the 3 buttons on the main screen opens separate view. how i supposed to do that? i will be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open different views with respective `UIButton` you need to use `UITabBar`. In tab bar you change add  `UITabBar` items. 
Or you can use `UINavigationBar` in place of `UITabBar`. In each `UIButton` you have to add action events. Suppose you are moving from `view1` to `view2`, then in `view1` in action event of `button1` you need to add

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

in View2 to return from that view2 to view1 you need to add

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Or you can add action events to the buttons . There you can switch one view to other by writing

```
[self.view addSubView:view1.view];
```

Here `view1` is the reference of next view which you want to switch. 
If you want to again come back to previous view then write in `UIButton` action

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to create 3 `UIButtons` and add them as `outlets` to your code and connect them to the interface builder. You will need to add them for other views but at a different location on where you want them to be... For opening a separate view on a button click, implement `Navigation` in the `IBAction` of each button and `PushViewController` to the specific view you want it to be.

Some suggestions :

1. Implement three `UIButtons` in a separate file and just add them to each view by just referencing it.
2. Seems like you have all 3 buttons in all views.... Why don't you just use a `UITabBarController` and make those buttons your `UITabBarItems` ? It will just make your development much more easier and look better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a method for the button in delegate, and you have to give a target to the method in your application delegate, and then set the delegate as `appDelegate`.

```
{
[buttonName addTarget:appDelegate action:@selector(methodname) forControlEvents:<#(UIControlEvents)controlEvents#>];
}
```